Filter items from Current Mailbox in outlook with python just like the outlook client?
I would like to filter out email subjects received within today from all emails that scattered in more than 100 of folders. I normally use the search bar to search the Mailbox directly but it seems like win32com doesn't support it?
I have tried Application.AdvanceSearch but there are not a lot of documentation for it and it seems like it have a different attribute setting than the official vba document.
It would be nice if anyone could provide a solution to filter from all emails with win32com.
Some of the failed code:
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def main():
    outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    test = outlook.AdvancedSearch("'Inbox', 'Sent Items'", "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Test'")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath\file_extration.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "mypath\file_extration.py", line 5, in main
    test = outlook.AdvancedSearch("Current Mailbox")
  File "<COMObject Outlook.Application>", line 2, in AdvancedSearch
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The operation failed.', None, 0, -2147023281), None)

